# Xamarin android c# call or display an activity after 3 second

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to call an activity after 3 second. I have tried use thread but it doesn't work......

```
[Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
        Button myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button4);

        myButton.Click += delegate
        {

            StartActivity(typeof(Register));
        };


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
    {
        //After 3 second will call this activity
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
    }, 5000);


    }    

}
```

Comment: Do you want to start Register Activity after 3 seconds delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    myButton.Click += async delegate
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        StartActivity(typeof(Register));
    };
```

Syntax with lambda

```
myButton.Click += async (sender, args) =>
{
     await Task.Delay(3000);
     StartActivity(typeof (Register));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
 Java.Lang.Runnable runnable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(() =>
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(i);
        });

        new Handler().PostDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```